# Show image from URL with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, url, xamarin.forms

I am using this code to show image from an URL

#### .xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="LandAHand.VolunteerView">
    <ContentPage.Content>
         <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Maroon">
             <Image x:Name="backgroundImage" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" />
         </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

#### .cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace LandAHand
{
    public partial class VolunteerView : ContentPage
    {
        public VolunteerView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            backgroundImage.Source = new UriImageSource
            {
                Uri = new Uri("https://s9.postimg.org/aq1jt3fu7/handshake_87122244_std.jpg"),
                CachingEnabled = true,
                CacheValidity = new TimeSpan(5, 0, 0, 0)
            };
        }
    }
}
```

This code is successfully working with iOS but it is not working with Android.

Comment: i just tested this and it works.

Answer (score 18):

Well you can do  this thing easier with your Xaml just make your xaml like this

```
<Image x:Name="backgroundImage" Source="https://s9.postimg.org/aq1jt3fu7/handshake_87122244_std.jpg" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
```

And remove the code related in the code behind. The cashing is enabled by default for 24 hours

Comment: Working fine in IOS device but not working in android device

Comment: how about if you put it inside a stacklayout instead of absolute? and try it on different devices

Answer (score 6):

It's not working because you use a https url.
For fix it, you should be configure your Android Project like this :
In Project Options > Android Options, click Advanced Options
HttpClient implementation : choose Android
SSL/TLS implementation : choose Native TLS 1.2+

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=windows

And update all Xamarin.Android packages

Comment: did not work for me